# Bittorrent sync approval process not working properly

Tags: bittorrent-sync

I created a link to share a folder, deselecting the option that peers I invite must be approved on this device.

The other person used the link, and received a message that the "Sender needs to approve access to this folder based on these identity details".

My bittorrent sync window isn't showing me anything to indicate that someone is waiting on approval.  I've never shared a folder via a link before (always just used keys directly on previous versions), so I have no idea how the program is supposed to prompt me for approval, and I can't find any documentation indicating how this prompt would be provided.

So there seem to be two problems here:
1. Even though I said the link doesn't require approval, they are being told that it does.
2. I don't have any way to approve it.

What's going on here?  How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this is one of the systems having clock time out of sync too much, usually resetting your computers time using an online time server resolves it.